# Found an unexpected mach-o header code in Xcode?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

So the error I'm having is this : "found an unexpected mach-o header code"

[image]

Everything I found online told me to check my target build phases and see what doesn't belong in the Copy Bundle Resources.

What doesn't belong here because I feel everything is in the right spot.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE : I removed everything in the list and I still encounter this error :(

Comment: I had this error too and found cleaning out anything in 'Link Binary With Libraries' in the Build Phases did the trick.

Comment: Those are my frameworks, I need those...

Comment: I'm getting the same error using Xcode 8 - Beta 2.  The same project compiles fine with Beta 1.  Somehow when I converted to Beta 2 and ran the app, my Pods.framework file was removed and I got the Mach-O header error.  When I went back to Beta 1, it compiled again and I see the Pods.Framework file now.

Comment: Same here. Been pulling my hair for the last couple hours trying to understand why beta 2 won't build my project when beta 1 will. Have you found any workarounds?

Comment: Nope, I'm still stuck here :(

Comment: @AmitNivedanKalra have you been able to solve this?

Comment: nah I think it's related to Fabric

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Cocoapods, you should add this to the end of your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Credits should go to https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5598

Comment: i dont use cocoapods

Comment: This is saved my day! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 hours of trying everything on the internet this is what fixed my solution

> 1. If you are using fabric, remove it. ( This helped some but not me, if it still didn't solve the problem move on to next one)
> 2. **Remove** Pod framework from "General" > "**Embedded binaries**" and add it back in "**Linked Frameworks**"
> 3. Remove **Derived Data**
> 4. Pod Update
> 5. Clean and Build

This finally helped me ( step 2 helped me the most) hope it helps you too

Comment: didnt use pods but i reverted back to the old version of the framework

Answer (score -1):

i got the same error... Clean project and build again works for me...

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. Please, read the rules of this community and welcome :)